# dotnetopenauth XRDS Clear Cache

Tags: asp.net, dotnetopenauth

I am using dotnetopenauth as an openid provider and have changed the Response.ApplyAppPathModifier file to a different file but the old one is always returned. The XRDS seems to be cached.

```
<URI><%=new Uri(Request.Url, Response.ApplyAppPathModifier("~/server.aspx"))%></URI>
```

Where is is cached?

Can I clear this?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,

Graham

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question, your OP endpoint is at a different path than server.aspx, and you've changed your XRDS file to reflect this, but RPs are still attempting to connect at server.aspx.  Is that right?

...assuming it is...

Your OP typically doesn't cache this, but RPs often cache discover results for some period of time.  It may just be that RPs haven't noticed the change yet.  You can try some OP tests at http://test-id.org, as any RP-side cache there has been disabled, to see if you got it right.

Another possibility is that your OP has two XRDS documents -- one for user identity URLs and one for your OP identifier.  Make sure you change *both* of them with your new OP endpoint.

Comment: Hi Andrew,

Thanks for your answer and all the work you have put into DotNetOpenAuth! I did change both files to my new OP endpoint but my test  RP site on localhost is still caching the old endpoint. 

http://test-id.org is returning the correct page.

I have tried clearing the .net cache but this has not helped. I am using the example web forms  RP included with DotNetOpenAuth 3.3.1. How is the endpoint cached. Is it via .net cache or some other method?

Graham

Comment: How do you clear the .NET cache?  You can disable the caching on the RP side using `<openid cacheDiscovery="false">` as described here: http://trac.dotnetopenauth.net:8000/wiki/CodeSnippets/Configuration

Comment: Thks adding that to the web.config did the trick! 

I tried to clear the asp.net cache using using the function shown at http://www.aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/How-to-clear-your-ASP-NET-applications-Cache.aspx but it did not clear the cached endpoint.